# How do I create column headers using CsvHelper?

Tags: c#, .net, csv, csvhelper

So I just installed CsvHelper because that's the one I heard was the better one to use.
I looked at the documentation and tried to figure out how to accompish what I wanted which is to create 1 column and fill it with values that are seperated with commas (`,`).
And then a cell under that one that would have the corresponding value so like this

```
ID,Type,Name,Description,Image
11,Variation,MyCoolProduct,A super cool product, Image1 | Image2
```

I dont want different columns to the side I want to have 1 column with a string inside that is formated like that.

This is what I did, which didnt work because you cant even open the file because you get a SYLK format issue

```
var records = new List<Columns>
{
    new Columns {ID = 12, Type = "Variation", Description = "Simple product with different colors",
                 Images = "Image1 | Image 2", Price = 19.99d}
    };

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("Testfile.csv"))
{
    var writer = new CsvWriter(sw);
    writer.WriteRecords(records);
}
```

UPDATE

I've mapped it like this now, how do i write it out to a textfile?

```
public sealed class MyClassMap : ClassMap<Columns>
    {
        public MyClassMap()
        {
            Map(m => m.ID);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should generally create a CsvClassMap class and map your class to the CSV format you need.

It's really simple and has a nice fluent interface.  Just do something like:

```
   public class ColMap : CsvClassMap<Column>
   {
       public ColMap()
       {
           Map(m=>m.ID).Name("ID").Index(0);
           .
           .
           .
       }
    }
```

Some of the other options after the .Index call will allow you to further configure the format of each of your columns.

Comment: Is CsvClassMap something that comes with the library?

Comment: It is indeed.   You also need to put the CSVWriter in a using, something I didn't notice before.

Comment: Ahh sorry, in the newer versions it's just called ClassMap, I forgot about that!

Comment: Updated my question with th classmap, how do i write it out to a csv file as I explained with like 1 column being 1 long string with the values seperated by a `,` ?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand.  What you mean by 1 long column but also separated?